# WebCAT for (Virginia Tech) submission won't allow me to submit this

Tags: java

Can someone tell me what's wrong with this?? This is what webcat is saying!

**[PL10] in PlayList.removeSong(1) with 3 songs:
 PlayList has wrong contents after removeSong
[PL11] in PlayList.removeSong(2) with 3 songs: PlayList has wrong contents after removeSong
[PL12] in PlayList.removeSong(int) with 3 songs: PlayList should be unchanged after removeSong with bad index
[PL13] PlayList has wrong contents after PlayList.removeSong(Song) when a Song occurs >1 time
[PL14] exception calling PlayList.removeSong(Song) with list of 3 songs**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PlayList {
private String name;
private ArrayList<Song> songList;

public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}

public String setName(String name) {
    return this.name = name;
}

public ArrayList getsongList() {
    return this.songList;
}

public ArrayList setsongList(ArrayList songList) {
    return this.songList = songList;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "PlayList [name= " + name + ",  Songlist = " + songList + "]";
}

public PlayList() {
    this.name = "Untitled";
}

public PlayList(String newName) {
    this.name = newName;
    songList = new ArrayList<Song>(); // add for both constructors
}

/**
 * Longest method. Takes input from file, converts it to string and displays
 * song or 'loads' it
 **/
public boolean loadSongs(String filename) {
    try {
        File text = new File(filename);
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(text);
        while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
            String art = "anything";
            String sng = "somethingelse";

            for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
                if (i == 0) {
                    art = scan.nextLine().trim();
                    if (art.length() == 0) {
                        continue;
                    }

                }
                if (i == 1) {
                    sng = scan.nextLine();
                }
                if (i == 2) {
                    String[] duration = scan.nextLine().split(";");
                    int m = Integer.parseInt(duration[0]); // like 1:
                    int s = Integer.parseInt(duration[1]); // like 135
                    int sec = 0;
                    int min = 0;
                    int rem = 0;
                    if (s >= 60) { // if s = 135
                        sec = s / 60; // sec = 2.25, or 2
                        rem = s % 60; // rem = 15
                        s = rem; // s is now 15
                        min = m * sec + m; // 1*2 + 1 = 3
                    }

                    Song anysong = new Song(art, sng, min, s);
                    songList.add(anysong);

                }

            }

        }

        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}

public boolean clear() {

    if (!songList.isEmpty()) {
        songList.clear();
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

public boolean addSong(Song s) {
    if (songList.add(s)) {
        return true;

    }
    return false;
}

public Song removeSong(int index) {
    index = 0;
    int i = 0;
    // check to see if the index is in the boundaries of the songList
    if (index >= 0 && index < songList.size()) {
        for (i = 0; i < songList.size(); i++) {
            return songList.remove(i);
        }
        return songList.remove(i);
    }

    else {
        return null;
    }

    // else return null
    // if ( index >= 0 && index < songList.size()

}

public Song removeSong(Song s) {
    boolean found = false;
    for (int j = 0; j > songList.size(); j++) {
        songList.remove(s);
        if (songList.remove(j).equals(songList.remove(j + 1))) {
            found = true;
            return s;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
        // compare all of these .equals()
        // what your doing right now is deleting all the songs
        // if you find that two are true, set ffound = true
        // then return s if found is true, return null if found is false
    }
    return s;
}

// getSong method

public Song getSong(int index) {
  int i = 0;
    if (index >= 0 && index <= songList.size()) {
      for (i = 0; i < songList.size(); i++) {
            return songList.get(i);
        }
  }
  return songList.get(i);
}

// it is similar to the removeSong(int Index)
// you need the same if statement

public void play(Song s) {
    for (int z = 0; z > songList.size(); z++) {
        System.out.println(songList);
    }
}

public int size() {
    return songList.size();
}
```

}

Comment: Thank you so much! That problem is gone, but now there are other problems too :/

Comment: Well, you can upvote/accept any correct answers to this question and then open a new question with your new problems.

Comment: @roippi No, it's a (not necessarily very readable) way to assign, and return the right-hand-side at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your problem:

```
public ArrayList setsongList(ArrayList songList) {
    return this.songList = songList;
}
```

This is accepting and returning a raw type of `ArrayList` while the field `this.songList` is an `ArrayList<Song>`. This is a big no-no. Revise your code to take the parametrized type as an argument, and return the parametrized type.

Revised version

```
public ArrayList<Song> setsongList(ArrayList<Song> songList) {
    return this.songList = songList;
}
```

Comment: Um can you tell me exactly what to change? Because it's not accepting return this.songList either

Comment: @AliKhan Are you sure that the error is still the same? Did you change the return type and argument type to be parametrized? Since Virginia Tech might have some sort of anti-plagiarism policy (I have no way of knowing), I cannot provide the exact code you'll need.

Comment: Well all I did was change it the parameter to ArrayList<Song> instead of ArrayList but it's still the same, do I have to change the return statement?

Comment: @AliKhan you need to change the declared return *type*. The return *statement* itself is fine.

Comment: oh, so you mean change it to public ArrayList<Song> setSongList(..) I'm assuming.

Comment: @AliKhan yes, exactly. I've never submitted anything to such a grading system, but I'm fairly sure that this would resolve the provoke problem.

Comment: @Takendarkk I am currently on a mobile device and editing code is unwieldy. I will try once I am back on a desktop computer unless an edit it suggested first.

Comment: Since you approve, I will do it for you now.